# How dynamically define properties for JPA connection with Injected EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, persistence.xml

How can I configure persistence.xml for production? My question specifically concerns the definition of parameters such as user, password and bank url, for example.

I would like to not include this data directly in the file, but in an environment variable, for example.

**However, it can be any other approach, except overwriting the file settings via the entity manager factory as was said in these questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836834/read-environment-variables-in-persistence-xml-file) e [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106078/dynamic-jpa-connection)**

This restriction exists because my `EntityManager` is injected via `@PersistenceContext`. This even generated a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8945953/8303951)

I'm using a JavaEE application with JAX-RS, Hibernate JPA and Spring MVC

Comment: It's a JavaSE application or JavaEE? If you are on a JavaEE server you should use a datasource to provide connections

Comment: I edited the question and a i included: I'm using a JavaEE application with JAX-RS, Hibernate JPA and Spring MVC. However, can you detail more what you said about "use a datasource to provide connections? @areus"

Comment: On a JavaEE server you can define a datasource, with all the connection properties, and on the persistence.xml you only need to add the `<jta-datasource>` tag referencing the JNDI name of the datasource.